# Reset a tag badge award time after a synonym approval

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-badges

A few months ago, I received the [ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) bronze tag badge. And I was the 5th person being awarded this badge. A few days ago, after the [ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) tag was approved as a synonym of the tag [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools). After that I received a notification that I received the [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools) bronze tag badge since it became the main tag and [ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) is considered as synonym.

But when you visit the [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools) bronze badge [holder page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8529/sql-server-data-tools), all tag holders are considered awarded this badge at the same time. And all tag awarded times are reset to the tag synonym approval. And now I become the third person in the list.

Is this a bug? It seems as the new tag is considered as separated from the old one.

[image]

Comment: Technically you aren't the third, but the first. You just happen to share that first place with 4 others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is again by design. When synonymized, the new tag name is taken into consideration. If you had a [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools) tag badge already, then you would not have been assigned a new tag badge. However since, [ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) was synonymized to the other one, and you had the [ssdt] badge, you received a new shiny one at the same time as others.

The tag syncing process runs at around 4:00 UTC every day, which is why you have received the badge at 4:05.

Comment: Not going to edit a single-character typo, but [tag:sqk-server-data-tools] should be [tag:sql-server-data-tools]

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, you _can_ edit typos. :)

Comment: I know, but I'm working on curbing my OCD :)

Comment: Did yuo mean ODC?

Comment: ARGH!! That's *cruel*!!